# Content block min-height

Tags: html, css

I have next situation atm.

[image]

Left column = content column, right column = additional.

Notice that content column has height, based on content in it. More content => more content block height.

I want to set min-height of this block. Look at right column. It has more height then left. It is not nice (usability, beauty). I want to make left column with fixed height than.

I have next html code:

```
<section>
    <div class='header'><h1><?=$PageHeader;?></h1></div>
    <div class='content'>
        <? include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$PageContent); ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

And css:

```
section {
    float: left;
    width: 770px;
    min-height: 500px;
}

section > div.content {
    /* many other options */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I set min-height of `section` (parent) and 100% height of `div.content` (child) but nothing happened. Why?

Comment: what browser are you currently using

Comment: Firefox. But I need all browsers support :)

Comment: * nothing happened* what exactly does this mean? how do you know? after try changing the content?

Comment: The min-height of 500px works - I have just tested it

Comment: @IPADDRESS I tested it too, it works, but it is not good way I think.

Comment: @KingKing I set up css, reloaded page and block height is still not 500px. Nothing happened. Sry for my english.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Can you elaborate on what you actually desire, please?

Comment: @IPADDRESS I did it in my question. I just said, that your method is a bit dirty I think, isn't it? I am setting `min-height: 500px;` of parent element and `height: 100%;` of child element. Now all child elements must be at least 500px. I thought so and did so, but it isn't working. At least explain me why my method not working , please :(

Comment: @SharikovVladislav hello, I think the wrong style is being inherited here

Comment: @IPADDRESS firebug shows that all styles inherited correctly.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav ok i will look at the code again

Comment: It becomes easier if the header is fixed height.

Comment: @SalmanA you mean header of whole page or header of section?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav: the header of section. Assume you fix it to 100px then min height of section > .content becomes 400px and you're done.

Comment: @SalmanA tried it and nothing happened. I tried to add `height` to `section > div.header`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/salman/xJt3n/2/ (short content) and http://jsfiddle.net/salman/xJt3n/3/ (tall content)

Comment: @SalmanA well, I tried this method already, it worked, but dirty, I think. Ok, I will use it then. Thank you.